# Why does the law of distributivity use the distributive property to prove it exists?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, fractions, rational-numbers

I was looking at the *Law of Distributivity* and disagreed with how it was proven. It proved that $$\frac ab\bigg(\frac cd + \frac ef\bigg) = \frac ab\cdot \frac cd + \frac ab\cdot \frac ef.$$ It multiplied $(c\div d)$ by $(f\div f)$ and it multiplied $(e\div f)$ by $(d\div d)$. Of course, the left hand side of the equation remains unchanged, i.e. $$\frac ab\bigg(\frac cd+\frac ef\bigg)=\frac ab\bigg(\frac cd\cdot \frac ff+\frac ef\cdot \frac dd\bigg)=\frac ab\bigg(\frac{cf}{df}+\frac{ed}{fd}\bigg).$$ This is because $(f\div f)$ and $(d\div d)$ each equal $1$. Now notice that $df=fd$, so since the fraction pair in the brackets have the same denominator, it can be combined, i.e. $$\frac ab\bigg(\frac{cf}{df}+\frac{ed}{fd}\bigg)=\frac ab\cdot\frac{cf+ed}{df}=\frac{a(cf+ed)}{bdf}.$$ The proof now follows by stating that $a(cf+ed)=acf+aed$, but this is the kind of property it is trying to prove in the first place. It is trying to prove this sense of distribution, and in it, it uses it to prove itself.

How is this allowed?

---

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932284/why-exactly-does-the-distributive-property-work) is very much related, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: It proves *distributivity* for fractions (i.e. *rationals*) assuming the distributivity for *integers*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ok, thank you.... but aren't integers rational themselves?

Comment: See [Number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number#Classification).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am fully aware of the different number systems, but say $a$ was an integer, then there exist values $A$ and $a_0$ such that $A\div a_0=a$. This makes $a$ rational, e.g. $5=10\div 2$. Do we have to use Peano Axioms to prove distributive property for *strictly* naturals (or integers, but we can just swap the sign)? I mean, this distribute law is proving the property for rationals... assuming that integers (being rational themselves) also fit the law. That's where I don't understand.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much! You can submit that as an answer if you wish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a "foundational" approach, we have to start from "bottom" : the *natural* numbers with their axioms: [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Multiplication) an the properties proved from them.

Then we have *integers*, defined as pair $(n,m)$ of naturals: in this way, $(n,0)$ is $n$ and $(0,m)$ is $−m$.

Then we have *rationals* that are (equivalence classes) of integers : $(r,s)$ with $s≠0$.

Thus, starting from Peano axioms, we proved *distributivity* for *naturals*.

Then we use it to prove distributivity for *integers* which, in turn, allows us to prove distributivity for *rationals*.

---

See : Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2011).