# Is multiplication of denominators in fractions a consequence of the associativity law of multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic, axioms

$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}$. If at first we divide only by **b**, and then their result by **d**, It is clear to me. I do not understand why if we divide directly by **bd**, it will give the same result? Is this a consequence of the axiom of associativity law (if I rewrite this as $a\cdot c\cdot b^{-1}\cdot d^{-1}$)?

I know how to operate with fractions, I'm interested in mathematical confirmation.

For example, I want to reduce the number 16 by 4 times, it will be 4. Then I want to reduce the number 4 by 4 times more. That is **16:4:4=1** or **16:16=1**, they are identical.

It's the same with multiplication, if I take the number 1 and want to increase it 4 times more, I get 4. Then I increase the number 4 four times more, I get 16. That is **1*4*4=16** or **1*16=16**, they are identical too.

I know that - no matter how much I try to calculate it, the result will be the same. But why does it work like this, it's just a fundamental property of multiplication - associativity? It's just a thing that doesn't have an explanation, it just works like that?

Sorry if this question is a duplicate, I didn't find the answer.

*I am not an expert in mathematics, my level of knowledge is high school.*

Thank for you answer.

Comment: You may be interested in the formal construction of the rational numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Formal_construction. The product formula is really a consequence of this construction. This may be out of reach at the high school level - but you can keep it in mind as you continue to learn.

Comment: Dupe of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337036/understanding-the-multiplication-of-fractions   Was wrongly gold-badge reopened by answerer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac ac$ is the number $x$ such that $cx = a$. $\dfrac bd$ is the number $y$ such that $dy=b$. What is $xy$? Well, $(cd)(xy) = (cx)(dy) = ab$. So this is a consequence of associativity *and* commutativity of multiplication (you need both).